# How to copy the functionality of the model browser?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

In the project sidebar, I display all the elements of which the model consists.

Now I need to make this list in its functionality was similar to the function that is triggered after pressing the button on the model browser.

In particular, I need that when I click on one of the items from the sidebar list that I created, it redirects me to the element that I clicked on, as it is done when using the model browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to react on the click event which I assume you get setup already. Then execute this code:

```
function (dbIds, model) {
    // dbIds can be either an array of dbId (int), or a single dbId (int)
    // model is the model object to which dbId belongs to
    if ( dbIds === -1 || (Array.isArray(dbIds) && dbIds.length === 0 ) {
        viewer.select([], undefined, model);
    } else {
        viewer.select(dbIds, model);
        viewer.fitToView([dbIds], model, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it really helped to solve